# resize a canvas and duplicate the resized content inside another one

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

How can I duplicate the content of a resized canvas inside another one?

If I draw an image inside a canvas and then I resize it, when I'll clone the content I duplicate the first canvas at its original size, even if it's resized.

html:

```
<img id="image" src="the-image.png" width="275" height="95"/>
<canvas id="canvas-image" width="275" height="95"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas-little" width="138" height="48"></canvas>
```

js:

```
var img = $('image');   

var cnvImage = $('canvas-image');
ctxImage = cnvImage.getContext('2d');
ctxImage.drawImage(img,0,0);

cnvImage.setStyles({ 'width': 138, 'height': 48 });

var cnvLittle= $('canvas-little');
ctxLittle = cnvLittle.getContext('2d');
ctxLittle.drawImage(cnvImage,0,0);
```

Comment: Hey, to make it easier to help, you should put your example up on jsfiddle or something like it. http://jsfiddle.net/  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/60/

Comment: @ellisbben completely rewritten the question, thanks a lot!

Comment: and here is the http://jsfiddle.net/jkXUJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the size of the canvas element *does not* change the size of the underlying image raster.  This is exactly like `img` tags, where changing the size does not change the actual contents of the image.

If you want to draw a scaled version of an image, you should just use the five-argument version of `context2d.drawImage()`:

```
context.drawImage(image, destinationX, destinationY, destinationHeight, destinationWidth);
```

[Your example, updated](http://jsfiddle.net/eFkK5/2/)

[The canvas spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#images) is an excellent place to go; it's a lot to read but, like eating your vegetables, it's good for you.

Comment: if it was the canvas spec that did it for you, you just made my bookmark manager blush.